# bar button item add toolbar programmatically

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I want to add  button instead of bar button item into toolbar programmatically. I select it because button has image infodark defaut.

so how is this done programmatically?

Comment: you add a view on toolbar and then add a button on that toolbar thats work.first try with direct add button on toolbar if not then try with view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:defaultImage];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[button setTitle:@"Display" forState:UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:selectedImage] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(button_Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Comment: to add bar buttton item to toolbar



self.forwardButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:nil action:nil];



NSArray *toolBarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:forwardButton,nil];

// Set toolar items

[self.toolBar setItems:toolBarItems];   

// add items to toolbar

[self addSubview:self.toolBar];

EDIT

In case you want to add Space between barbuttonitems

UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:NULL];

Answer (score 0):

To add this button in `UIToolbar` you need this code.
first you can initialize `UIToolbar` after that

```
NSMutableArray *buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

[buttons addObject: barButtonItem];
[buttons addObject: btnFav];
[buttons addObject: btnGeneralPopOverController];
[buttons addObject: showInfo];   

[mytoolbar setItems:buttons animated:NO];
```