# Done button in uitoolbar

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

Is there anyway to limit the Done button's frame in uitoolbar.I want it to be positioned to the rightside. The problem i face is that the action for done button gets called even if i tap outside the done button in the uitoolbar.I want the done action to be called only if the user taps on it. Can anyone tell me what i should do in the below code.

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneWriting:)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
//flexible.width=310;
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexible,doneButton, nil]];
[doneButton release];
[flexible release];

labelItems = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:(IS_IPAD ? CGRectMake(20, 5, 550, 70) : CGRectMake(10, 0, 223, 40))];
labelItems.delegate=self;
labelItems.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:(IS_IPAD ? 33 : 15)];
labelItems.inputAccessoryView = toolBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UIbutton In UIBarButtonItem.

Please See this link

[bar button item add toolbar programetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10444104/bar-button-item-add-toolbar-programetically)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply and is there any possiblity to add the done button the way i did using the UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace with the button having its frame correctly set?

Comment: I faced lots of time this problem that's why I used UIbutton In UIBarButtonItem.